# Why was my question closed then deleted?

Tags: support

[This question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12557/resolve-overlapping-subnet-problem-using-linux-and-iptables/12581#12581) was deleted by [Ron Maupin](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8499/ron-maupin) but I disagree that this wasn't a business related question.  I was tasked by our customer to resolve an issue where they were unable to access a remote server due to an overlapping subnet.  This is what Ron had to say:

"NE is a site for to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks in a business environment. Your question falls outside the areas our community decided are on topic. Please visit the help center for more details. If you disagree with this closure, please ask on Network Engineering Meta."

This was indeed a professionally managed network (sorry, I cannot name the company here but I can say it was a major in the Oil and Gas industry).  I was trying to search for this question again as I have yet again another similar problem and was trying to refer to the solution I had for the previous customer.  I'd like this question reopened as I see no reason it was ever closed in the first place!

Moderators need to be moderated for when they take dictatorial action meking themselves judge, jury, and executioner.

Comment: The problem with that question and answer is that it is for host/server configurations that are off-topic here. I'm not sure why it is deleted, but it was properly closed as off-topic.

Comment: I have no issue with it being closed as off-topic, but the annoying bit is that it got deleted despite having an answer and having at least 2K views.  No matter how kludgy the solution, it is still a solution that works.  So, please undelete this so others in similar predicaments can at least find solace.  NOTE: It shows as being deleted by you, @ron-maupin

Comment: I undeleted it, but I do not know why I deleted it in the first place because it has been a couple of years. I must have been asked by someone, or there was another reason. Your last sentence is actually unfair and untrue. Remember that the community does not want such questions here, and the timeline shows six different close votes. It belongs on [sf], but it seems that the ability to migrate is gone from NE. I will see if we can get that back.

Comment: I appreciate your action to undelete and apologize for being harsh.

Comment: I share the analysis of @AnthonyK this is fully a network engineering question. If `iptables` are made to manage network filtering, trafic shaping, this is fully within the field of a professionnal network engineer. I can't understand why such a good quality question could be closed or worse deleted. •••• Are there too many good quality questions on this group?

Comment: @dan, iptables is a host configuration that should be asked on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network. Host configurations are off-topic for NE, which is for questions about the network an enterprise-grade network devices, not host configuration that are well-covered on other SE sites. NE was split off from [su] and [sf] to get professional network questions without trying to wade through all the host/server and consumer-grade device configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, closed questions can be deleted by the system. (i.e. "Community") However, it should never remove questions that have answers.

In this case, the history shows there was a vote to delete on Mar 3 '18 -- one year after it was closed. While it's true moderators don't get a vote - their actions are immediate, Ron was simply approving the "delete" vote.

Even back then, NE wasn't the place for such a question. You weren't asking *how* in a theoretical sense. You were looking for a specific means to configure linux iptables, which is not something relevant to NE. As this is a valid question in general, and has an answer, it should be moved to a different SE. (can a closed question also be "protected"?)